# How to get latitude, longtitude from country, region code using pygeoip

Tags: python, geoip

I have GeoIP city and region codes like so:

```
region_code:H9
country_code:GB
```

The city and region codes I have were obtained via GeoIP from IP address at some point in the past. However, IP address has not been retained.
I believe it should be possible to index into the GeoLite City database and retrieve latitude and longtitude with this info but I can't see anything out of the box in the pygeoip wrapper to do so. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoIP City provides a mapping from IP address to location (including coordinates). For instance:

```
>>> gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoIPCity.dat')
>>> gi.record_by_addr('64.233.161.99')
{
    'city': u'Mountain View',
    'region_code': u'CA',
    'area_code': 650,
    'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
    'dma_code': 807,
    'metro_code': 'San Francisco, CA',
    'country_code3': 'USA',
    'latitude': 37.41919999999999,
    'postal_code': u'94043',
    'longitude': -122.0574,
    'country_code': 'US',
    'country_name': 'United States',
    'continent': 'NA'
}
>>> gi.time_zone_by_addr('64.233.161.99')
'America/Los_Angeles'
```

However, it does not provide a mapping from region code to coordinates. For this, I would recommend using [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/).

Comment: apologies if I wasn't clear in my question: The city names and region codes I have were obtained via GeoIP from IP address at some point in the past. However, IP address has not been retained. Therefore I'm trying to go back the other way. The data must be in the database; but as you say maybe it's not straightforward to do. I don't think I'm able to use GeoNames that easily since the country/region codes I have are specific to GeoIP

Comment: The region codes and country code are not specific. The country codes are ISO and the region codes are FIPS codes for everywhere but the US and Canada, where they are ISO. GeoNames supports both FIPS and ISO. In their premium data set, they have mapping from FIPS and ISO to regions, but you can reconstruct it with their free data as well.

Comment: [This CSV](http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/misc/region_codes.csv) may also be useful.

Comment: So the combination of country and region code is not unique?? Surely there is only one 'CA' in 'US'??  The info supplied is useful (have upvoted your answer) will accept your answer if no-one else pops up with a way to do it using the data already in the GeoIP database! Or is what you're saying that there is no Lat / Long information associated with California,USA for example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the country and region codes are not _MaxMind_ specific. They use the ISO and FIPS standards (with a couple of exceptions like A1 for proxies). Another approach that may work for you is to use the GeoIP City CSV provided by MaxMind to get this information. If you are a customer, you should have access to the paid version. Otherwise, there is the [GeoLite](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/#Downloads) CSVs.

Comment: Ah I missed those CSVs. Yep they give exactly what I was looking for... just a couple of lines of python to turn it into a dictionary!